# How to access an element from an array based on the other arrays index in handlebars?

Tags: arrays, indexing, handlebars.js

I am currently having trouble accessing an element of an array based on the index of another array. Here is what I'm trying to do in a simplified version:

So I have 2 arrays that I pass to handlebars:

```
array1 = [Top, Mid, Jungle, ADC, Support]
array2 = [Gankplank, Ahri, Khazix, Ezreal, Janna]
```

Here is my simplified handlebars code:

```
{{#each array1}}
   {{this}} - {{array2.[@INDEX OF ARRAY 1]}}
{{/each}}
```

So my desired output would look like:

> Top - Gankplank
>   Mid - Ahri
>   Jungle - Khazix
>   ADC - Ezreal
>   Support - Janna

Comment: Merge this both array in to object and pass it to handlebarJS. refer my answer if you are okay with this approach !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below snippets to create object and pass this object to handlebar template.

In Underscore

```
var tplObj = _.object(['Top', 'Mid', 'Jungle'], ['Gankplank', 'Ahri', 'Khazix']);
// output => {'Top': 'Gankplank', 'Mid': 'Ahri', 'Jungle': 'Khazix'}
```

In Plain JS

```
var tplObj = {};
for(var i in array1) {
 tplObj[ array2[i] ] = array1[i];
}
```

Iterate Object in handlebar template like below

```
{{#each tplObj}}
    Key: {{@key}} Value = {{this}}
{{/each}}
```